# Delete the parent of a child

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

```
<ListBox>
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="button1" Click="buttonDelete_Click"></Button>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="button2" Click="buttonDelete_Click"></Button>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="button3" Click="buttonDelete_Click"></Button>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="button4" Click="buttonDelete_Click"></Button>
    </Grid>
</ListBox>
```

I'm using the button click event, I want to remove the `Grid` `((Button)sender).Parent` from the listbox, by so doing I also remove all the children of the grid including the button itself.

Please note that on my application I am adding 19 controls (including the button) on the Grid in code using c#.

Comment: cool stuff, but where's the question???

Comment: are you getting the Grid object from parent property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myListbox.Items.Remove(((sender as FrameworkElement).Parent)

Answer (score 3):

```
Grid grid =   (((Button)sender).Parent) as Grid;
if(grid != null)
{
   ListBox listbox = grid.Parent as ListBox;
   if(listbox != null)
   {
     listbox.Children.Remove(grid);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Grid _grid =   (Grid)(((Button)sender).Parent);
ListBox box = _grid.Parent as ListBox;
box.Children.Remove(_grid);
```